# Is there any automatic mapping between object and arguments list when calling to a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

My question came after seeing the method Jquery.clone()

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

This method has 3 optional arguments, but it is not required to provide them all. You can just simple create a JSON with the properties of your interest.

It seems that there's an automatic mapping between objects fields and the function's arguments. Is this done automatically or manually by the function's author?

For instance, I can call it with the second parameter only by doing this:

```
$('aSelector').clone({withDataAndEvents: true});
```

or

```
$('aSelector').clone(null true);
```

I'd like to write functions like this without testing if the provided argument is actually an object or a plain argument.

Comment: "Is this done automatically or manually by the function's author?"

Is what done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think, this is the source

```
clone: function( dataAndEvents, deepDataAndEvents ) {
    dataAndEvents = dataAndEvents == null ? false : dataAndEvents;
    deepDataAndEvents = deepDataAndEvents == null ? dataAndEvents : deepDataAndEvents;

    return this.map( function () {
        return jQuery.clone( this, dataAndEvents, deepDataAndEvents );
    });
},
```

and you can see that the author checks whether the parameters are set or not. the answer would be "manually"

Comment: This is correct if I call the function providing the arguments. But I'd like to know how is it done with an object as argument. See my updates

Comment: You could pass anything as an argument. You could write `$('aSelector').clone({friesWithThat: true});` and it would still pass true. This is because you are just passing a `var` that equals `true`, therefore `dataAndEvents = friesWithThat = true`, then if you remember your math, then transitive prop. leads to `dataAndEvents = true`